# Error changing function arguments to produce multiple outputs

Tags: python-3.x, function

When I uncomment this line after the function (changing one argument to get a second result set):

```
weights2 = weights(flags, 0, .4, .3, .3, 0, .4) ## This line is the problem
```

I receive this error:

TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable

**Input:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

flags = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['2017-11-01','2017-12-01','2018-01-01'],
                    'flag_11': [2, 2, 2],
                   'flag_12': [2, 2, 2]})

flags = flags.set_index('Date')
print(flags)
```

**Function:**

```
def weights(dfin, wt1, wt2, wt3, wmin06, wmin1012, wmax1012):
    dfin = pd.DataFrame(dfin)
    dfout = pd.DataFrame()
    dfcum = pd.DataFrame()
    mapping = {1:wt1,2:wt2,3:wt3}
    dfout['flag_12']=dfin['flag_12'].replace(mapping)
    dfcum['flag_12']=dfin['flag_12'].replace(mapping)
    i = 11
    conditions = [
    (dfin["flag_{}".format(i)]==1) & (wt1 > (wmax1012 - dfout["flag_{}".format(i+1)])),
    (dfin["flag_{}".format(i)]==1) & (wt1 < (wmin1012 - dfout["flag_{}".format(i+1)])),
    (dfin["flag_{}".format(i)]==1),
    (dfin["flag_{}".format(i)]==2) & (wt2 > (wmax1012 - dfout["flag_{}".format(i+1)])),
    (dfin["flag_{}".format(i)]==2) & (wt2 < (wmin1012 - dfout["flag_{}".format(i+1)])),
    (dfin["flag_{}".format(i)]==2),
    (dfin["flag_{}".format(i)]==3) & (wt3 > (wmax1012 - dfout["flag_{}".format(i+1)])),
    (dfin["flag_{}".format(i)]==3) & (wt3 < (wmin1012 - dfout["flag_{}".format(i+1)])),
    (dfin["flag_{}".format(i)]==3)]   
    choices = [
    (wmax1012 - dfout["flag_{}".format(i+1)]),
    (wmin1012 - dfout["flag_{}".format(i+1)]),
    (wt1),
    (wmax1012 - dfout["flag_{}".format(i+1)]),
    (wmin1012 - dfout["flag_{}".format(i+1)]),
    (wt2),
    (wmax1012 - dfout["flag_{}".format(i+1)]),
    (wmin1012 - dfout["flag_{}".format(i+1)]),
    (wt3)]
    dfout["flag_{}".format(i)] = np.select(conditions, choices)
    dfcum["flag_{}".format(i)] = np.select(conditions, choices)+dfcum["flag_{}".format(i+1)]
    dfout=dfout.iloc[:,::-1]
    dfcum=dfcum.iloc[:,::-1]
    return(dfout,dfcum)
weights = weights(flags, 0, .4, .025, .3, 0, .4)
# weights2 = weights(flags, 0, .4, .3, .3, 0, .4) ## This line is the problem
print(weights[0])
print(weights[1])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
weights = weights(flags, 0, .4, .025, .3, 0, .4)
```

This line shadows the function `weights` with the tuple `weights` which is returned from the function.

When you try to call the function the second time you are "calling" the tuple, hence the error `tuple is not callable`.

You have to use a different name for either the function or the return value, for example

```
calculated_weights1 = weights(flags, 0, .4, .025, .3, 0, .4)
calculated_weights2 = weights(flags, 0, .4, .3, .3, 0, .4)
```

Comment: Clear, thank you. Will accept answer after time limit is up in 8 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

No error after changing the result names to "out1", "out2", etc.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

flags = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['2017-11-01','2017-12-01','2018-01-01'],
                    'flag_11': [2, 2, 2],
                   'flag_12': [2, 2, 2]})

flags = flags.set_index('Date')
print(flags)

def weights(dfin, wt1, wt2, wt3, wmin06, wmin1012, wmax1012):
    dfin = pd.DataFrame(dfin)
    dfout = pd.DataFrame()
    dfcum = pd.DataFrame()
    mapping = {1:wt1,2:wt2,3:wt3}
    dfout['flag_12']=dfin['flag_12'].replace(mapping)
    dfcum['flag_12']=dfin['flag_12'].replace(mapping)
    i = 11
    conditions = [
    (dfin["flag_{}".format(i)]==1) & (wt1 > (wmax1012 - dfout["flag_{}".format(i+1)])),
    (dfin["flag_{}".format(i)]==1) & (wt1 < (wmin1012 - dfout["flag_{}".format(i+1)])),
    (dfin["flag_{}".format(i)]==1),
    (dfin["flag_{}".format(i)]==2) & (wt2 > (wmax1012 - dfout["flag_{}".format(i+1)])),
    (dfin["flag_{}".format(i)]==2) & (wt2 < (wmin1012 - dfout["flag_{}".format(i+1)])),
    (dfin["flag_{}".format(i)]==2),
    (dfin["flag_{}".format(i)]==3) & (wt3 > (wmax1012 - dfout["flag_{}".format(i+1)])),
    (dfin["flag_{}".format(i)]==3) & (wt3 < (wmin1012 - dfout["flag_{}".format(i+1)])),
    (dfin["flag_{}".format(i)]==3)]   
    choices = [
    (wmax1012 - dfout["flag_{}".format(i+1)]),
    (wmin1012 - dfout["flag_{}".format(i+1)]),
    (wt1),
    (wmax1012 - dfout["flag_{}".format(i+1)]),
    (wmin1012 - dfout["flag_{}".format(i+1)]),
    (wt2),
    (wmax1012 - dfout["flag_{}".format(i+1)]),
    (wmin1012 - dfout["flag_{}".format(i+1)]),
    (wt3)]
    dfout["flag_{}".format(i)] = np.select(conditions, choices)
    dfcum["flag_{}".format(i)] = np.select(conditions, choices)+dfcum["flag_{}".format(i+1)]
    dfout=dfout.iloc[:,::-1]
    dfcum=dfcum.iloc[:,::-1]
    return(dfout,dfcum)
out1 = weights(flags, 0, .4, .025, .3, 0, .4)
out2 = weights(flags, 0, .4, .3, .3, 0, .4) ## This line is the problem
print(out1[0])
print(out1[1])
print(out2[0])
print(out2[1])
```